# How to selectively enable or disable SSL for some URLs in Tomcat 7

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I am using SSL in Tomcat 7, create a keystore and configure `server.xml`, and also config in `web.xml` as below

```
<security-constraint>
         <!-- SSL enforced -->
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>SSL</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/inspectionGp/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/inspection/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/inspGpDt/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/inspDt/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

That works for SSL, these restricted URLs are forced to use only SSL, but other URLs can also use both HTTP and HTTPS, it's strange, I don't want use HTTPS for the URLs which are not configured in `<url-pattern>`. I use  `<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>`, that will result in all URLs support both HTTP and HTPPS. So can anybody help explain how I can resolve it?

Comment: Why? You're going to the trouble to enable SSL - why not just use it for everything?

Answer (score 4):

Definitely consider using SSL for everything.  Many of our clients are going this direction and I recommend it fully.

If you mix HTTP/HTTPS and want to maintain session state, you'll have to circumvent some of the mechanisms in Tomcat that try to prevent this (secure-only cookies for JSESSIONID).  Once you successfully do that, then somebody could possibly hijack a session from the HTTP and take actions on the HTTPS side.

All that said, if you want to have this level of fine-grained control, you could consider using a ServletFilter.  The filter could be applied first in the web.xml and be applied to the "REQUEST" dispatcher on the "/*" URL pattern (or just patterns where you need to make this determination).

The filter would then look at the request.  If it is a path that must be HTTPS it would check the request.isSecure().  If not secure it would issue a 301 redirect to the HTTPS side of things, making sure to maintain the full request path and any URL parameters.  Likewise to redirect from HTTPS over to HTTP.

I am passionately in love with servlet filters.  They are the Swiss Army Knife of request handling.  There is nothing you cannot do.  Most importantly, the behavior is part of the app and not a customization to the Tomcat setup.  You can deploy the app anywhere and it'll "just work".

Comment: but I just want to know whether tomcat has native configuration way to disable ssl for some url, such as static resources cause our static resource is also in tomcat.

Comment: Can you still hijack a session with the filter?

Comment: The biggest risk to hijacking a session is creating session cookies with secure=false.  However, the default behavior is to create with secure=true on an HTTPS request.  Thus, with the defaults, the HTTP side of things will not be in the same session as the HTTPS.  If this is acceptable you're set.  If you want to share session then you expose yourself to session hijacking.  One might be able to craft more complicated schemes (like cookie accessible on HTTP side that only provides enough access to know if logged-in and invalidate the session), but sounds like more trouble than it's worth.